# Angularjs Add new Record in json Temp Variabel

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am getting the current user id and fetching some details form the database.

```
$http.post('get-family-list.php', {user_id:user_id}).
    success(function(data, status) {
      $localStorage.family = data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status) {
      console.log('Cannot Retrieve Family List');  
  });
```

this code works, and then the user can add new record in the same view. I mean the CRUD operations are all in the same page and i am calling the above code in the app base controller. not in the CRUD page.

And in the CRUD controller..

```
$scope.family_list = $localStorage.family;
```

So now my problem is when the user created new record or editing the record, i can't update the listing.. I don't want to fetch the whole list from the server again. I want to add/update the new values to local storage variable $localStorage.family

I wrote this code within the success function of insert/update http request, its not working.

```
$scope.family_list[data.id] = {"nric":this.nric,"dob":date_of_birth,"name":this.name,"gender":this.gender,"relationship":this.relationship,"student":this.student};

$localStorage.family = $scope.family_list;
```

and my json values

```
{"4":{"ID":"4","UID":"26","nric":"sdf","dob":"01\/01\/1990","name":"a","gender":"1","relationship":"1","student":"1","created":"2015-06-03 11:04:29"},"5":{"ID":"5","UID":"26","nric":"aaaa","dob":"01\/01\/1990","name":"aaa","gender":"1","relationship":"1","student":"1","created":"2015-06-03 11:13:21"},"1":{"ID":"1","UID":"26","nric":"ad","dob":"17\/05\/1990","name":"asdf asf","gender":"1","relationship":"1","student":"1","created":"2015-06-02 21:33:59"},"2":{"ID":"2","UID":"26","nric":"ad new","dob":"24\/03\/1984","name":"asdf asf new","gender":"2","relationship":"2","student":"2","created":"2015-06-02 21:46:50"},"3":{"ID":"3","UID":"26","nric":"insert 113","dob":"01\/01\/1990","name":"insert update","gender":"1","relationship":"1","student":"1","created":"2015-06-03 10:41:23"},"6":{"ID":"6","UID":"26","nric":"adfsdf","dob":"01\/01\/1990","name":"sdfsdf","gender":"1","relationship":"1","student":"1","created":"2015-06-03 11:14:20"}}
```

Thanks to all

Comment: What is `this.nric`, etc..? I mean why `this`, shouldn't it be `data.nric`?

Comment: Why are you creating an associative array?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, all you have to do is $localStorage.family[data.id] = $scope.family_list[data.id];

Comment: wait i tell you in few mins.. this.nric is used to get the values from the form. Wait i tell you.

Comment: for add new yes works but one more issue.. for the dynamically added listing update is not working

Comment: @IoanaCucuruzan: your code also works but when i click the update, i can't retrieve the field values. but it works for the listing fetched from the server. When print the family_listing in the view {{family_list | json}} it works. It shows the newly added record.

Comment: SORRY UPDATE WORKS.. but when the db is empty the add new is not working..

Comment: You mean when $localStorage.family and $scope.family_list are empty, adding the first item doesn't work? Just initialize them at the top of your controller like this $localStorage.family = {}; $scope.family_list = {}; After that, the code should work as it is. If this does not help please show us the entire content of your file(s) to have a better idea of the workflow.

Comment: Great thanks, it works. I declared the localstorage as empty object/array but forgot to define the $scope.family variable.

Comment: finally one more issue. can you help me to delete the object from the json using the key values. for example i want to delete the object which has the key value 5. We have to assign null instead of adding or updating the values?

Comment: You can simply use: delete $localStorage.family[data.id];

Comment: Great works :) Thank you so much